# Strange output from AWK

Tags: text-processing, awk, special-characters

Trying to extract a column (UPC Number) from csv file and adding white spaces at the end in case the length of the file is less than 14. However the output have an ^M at the end which I do not know how to remove.

This command is working for other columns except for this one.

```
awk -F, '{print $8}' $FILE | awk '{printf("%-14s\n", $0) }' > $TEMP/upc
```

vi output:

```
861601000109^M

736040531685^M
```

cat output:

```
 61601000109

 36040531685
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file was probably opened and saved in a windows text editor.

The end of line character in UNIX based systems are different from that of windows.

> Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings
>   than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line
>   feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n").
>   You need to be careful about transferring files between Windows
>   machines and Unix machines to make sure the line endings are
>   translated properly.

[Source](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html)

When you `cat` the file, the EOL character will not be displayed, however, when you read the file using `vi`, it will be.

The easiest way to remove `^M` from the file, is probably to use the stream editor `sed` to remove the `^M` characters. Type this command: `% sed -e "s/^M//" filename > newfilename`

To enter `^M`, type `CTRL-V`, then `CTRL-M`. That is, hold down the CTRL key then press V and M in succession.

Comment: You can also use the nearly ubiquitous tool `dos2unix` to convert CRLF line-endings to LF line-endings.  (older) Mac-sourced files have a similar issue, as they had used CR as their line-endings.

Comment: `^M` can also be written `\r`.  And if you don't have the `dos2unix` utility, `vim` can be of some help: `vim -c 'set fileformat=unix' -c 'x' file`

Comment: you're right, I face it when I manipulate file which saved in Windows. but before editing, there are any characters like that.do you know the reason?